# Jquery: add one line to each class

Tags: jquery

I have class `dot` and have html code like that:

```
<span class="dot">Text1</span>
<span class="dot">Text2</span>
<span class="dot">Text3</span>
```

I want to add to each element who has class `dot` additional text automatically. For example, add `&#8226;` code that it would be

```
<span class="dot">&#8226; Text1</span>
<span class="dot">&#8226; Text2</span>
<span class="dot">&#8226; Text3</span>
```

I imagine it should be done with jquery, so any help?

Thanks.

Comment: If it can be done with CSS, I wouldn't use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using CSS instead of javascript? http://jsfiddle.net/SEvkJ/

```
​.dot:before {
    content: '\2022';
}
```

---

**EDIT:** If you want a space in there, then do this: http://jsfiddle.net/SEvkJ/1/

```
.dot:before {
    content: '\2022\00A0';
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's nice, I think I will use this one.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method:

```
jQuery(".dot").prepend("&#8226;");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.dot').text(function(index, old_text){return '\u2022 ' + old_text;});
```